# How to correct change a Label.Text

Tags: winforms

I"m new in VB and i have a problem with Label.
Example:

```
        public Form1()
    {
        Label.Text = "s";
       InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And when i run program , I"m getting:

```
System.NullReferenceException textBox1 was null.
```

How can I fix it ?
Same on TextBox.

Comment: `Label.Text = "s";` line should be after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: Always write your code after `InitializeComponent()` line. If the Label control is added to Form through designer it should work. If it is dynamically added don't miss instantiation that looks like: `Label myLabel = new Label();`

Comment: I"m an idiot :X Thx ! It worked :D